# Magento 1.9 check if two or mulltiple attributes have values

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes

I add three text field attribute in my product view.phtml, but i want to hide one text above only if none of that attributes have value.

This is my work but, "**PURCHASE FROM THESE RETAILERS**" is still in page, if i remove all attributes value in admin from (**amazon_com_link**, **amazon_com_link**, **amazon_ca_link**).

```
<?php if(in_array($_product->getAmazon_com_link) && ($_product->getAmazon_co_uk_link) && ($_product->getAmazon_ca_link) ) ?>

            <a style="font-size:20px;letter-spacing: normal;font-style: italic;font-weight: bolder;color: #fda221;"> PURCHASE FROM THESE RETAILERS 
            </a>

            <div class="buy-from">
                <?php if($_product->getAmazon_com_link()): ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo ($_product->getAmazon_com_link()) ?>"><img src="<?php $this->getSkinUrl(); ?>/amazonus-logo.jpg" alt="Buy from Amazon.com"></a>
                <?php endif ?>
                <?php if($_product->getAmazon_com_link()): ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo ($_product->getAmazon_co_uk_link()) ?>">
                        <img src="<?php $this->getSkinUrl(); ?>/amazonuk-logo.jpg" alt="Buy from Amazon.co.uk">
                    </a>
                <?php endif ?>
                <?php if($_product->getAmazon_ca_link()): ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo ($_product->getAmazon_ca_link()) ?>">
                        <img src="<?php $this->getSkinUrl(); ?>/amazonca-logo.jpg" alt="Buy from Amazon.ca">
                    </a>

            </div>

        <?php endif ?>
```

I want to show off text inside `<a></a>` if none of that three attributes have values.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with mine:

```
<?php if($_product->getAmazonComLink() && $_product->getAmazonCoUkLink() && $_product->getAmazonCaLink()) ?>

            <a style="font-size:20px;letter-spacing: normal;font-style: italic;font-weight: bolder;color: #fda221;"> PURCHASE FROM THESE RETAILERS 
            </a>

            <div class="buy-from">
                <?php if($_product->getAmazonComLink()): ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getAmazonComLink(); ?>"><img src="<?php $this->getSkinUrl(); ?>/amazonus-logo.jpg" alt="Buy from Amazon.com"></a>
                <?php endif ?>
                <?php if($_product->getAmazonComLink()): ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getAmazonComLink(); ?>">
                        <img src="<?php $this->getSkinUrl(); ?>/amazonuk-logo.jpg" alt="Buy from Amazon.co.uk">
                    </a>
                <?php endif ?>
                <?php if($_product->getAmazonCaLink()): ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getAmazonCaLink(); ?>">
                        <img src="<?php $this->getSkinUrl(); ?>/amazonca-logo.jpg" alt="Buy from Amazon.ca">
                    </a>

            </div>

        <?php endif ?>
```